# Яндекс карты API: увеличить "плотность" отображаемых названий населённых пунктов

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, есть ли в yandex-maps-api настройка, с помощью которой можно регулировать "плотность" отображаемых названий населённых пунктов на карте?
Сейчас, чтобы увидеть названия небольших и маленьких населённые пункты, необходимо изменять масштаб карты (сильно приближать). При этом на карте достаточно места для отображения наименований и без приближения карты.

Текущее отображение:
[image: Текущее отображение]

Хотелось бы так (больше названий населённых пунктов БЕЗ увеличения масштаба):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В API v3 нет слоя со спутниковыми данными. А в API 2.1, развитие которого более не планируется, слой дорог и названий топонимов реализован так же, как и сама подложка, — предварительно отрендеренными тайлами. Слой этот отрисован в единственном варианте для каждого масштаба и настройке не подлежит.